# create list of each siblings children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple sections with multiple sub-sections. Each section should have a list of all sub-section h3-headings within this section. Given this HTML:

```
<div class="allwrap">
    <div class="main-section" id="m1">  
       <h2>Main-1-Headline</h2>
       <ul class="sub-sections-list">
           <!-- generate LIs of each [#main-1 > .sub-section h3 text] -->
       </ul>        
       <div class="sub-section" id="m1-s1">         
           <h3>Main-1-Sub-1-Headline</h3>
       </div>       
       <div class="sub-section" id="m1-s2">         
           <h3>Main-1-Sub-2-Headline</h3>
       </div>               
   </div>   
   <div class="main-section" id="main-2">
       <h2>Main-2-Headline</h2>
       <ul class="sub-sections-list">
           <!-- generate LIs of each [#main-2 > .sub-section h3 text] -->
       </ul>        
       <div class="sub-section" id="m2-s1">         
           <h3>Main-2-Sub-1-Headline</h3>
       </div>       
       <div class="sub-section" id="m2-s2">         
            <h3>Main-2-Sub-2-Headline</h3>
        </div>              
    </div>  
</div>
```

So I iterate over each sections subsection H3 and have an array of ALL h3-headings now which is not what i want to accomplish:

```
var myList = [];
$('.main-section .sub-section').each(function(){
    myList.push($(this).find('h3').text());
}); 
$.each(myList, function(){
    var li = $('<li/>').appendTo('.sub-sections-list');
    $('<a/>').attr('href', '#').text(this).appendTo(li);
});
```

How can i make it so that not all h3-headings of all sections are in the list but only the headings of the respective parent section? The result should look like this:

Main-1-Headline (begin of Main-section-1)

- Main-1-Sub-1-Headline
- Main-1-Sub-2-Headline

  Main-1-Sub-1-Headline (begin of sub-section-1)

  Some content here (not in above HTML for keeping it simple)

  Main-1-Sub-2-Headline (begin of sub-section-2)

  Some content here (not in above HTML for keeping it simple)

Main-2-Headline (begin of Main-section-2)

- Main-2-Sub-1-Headline
- Main-2-Sub-2-Headline

  Main-2-Sub-1-Headline (begin of sub-section-1)

  Some content here (not in above HTML for keeping it simple)

  Main-2-Sub-2-Headline (begin of sub-section-2)

  Some content here (not in above HTML for keeping it simple)

Comment: please add an image to make things clear!

Comment: An image of what? the code?

Comment: How the sections and sub sections will appear, image of that

Comment: An image is useless, if you want a demonstration of the code try http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (optimized version):

```
$('.main-section').each(function(){
  var ul = $(this).find('.sub-sections-list');
  $(this).find('h3').each(function(){
    ul.append('<li><a href="#">'+$(this).text()+'</a></li>');
  });
});
```

Example: https://jsbin.com/gefupivoji/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Exactly what i want, many thx!
I voted this answer, because i like the shorter version compared to NiZas answer, which also seems to be correct. Both answers help me a lot for further understanding.

Comment: @Gregor i just like to show how code could be optimized :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this.

**Updated short way demo**

```js
$('.main-section h3').each(function(){
  $(this).parent().prevAll(".sub-sections-list").append('<li><a href="#">'+$(this).text()+'</a></li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="allwrap">
  <div class="main-section" id="m1">
    <h2>Main-1-Headline</h2>
    <ul class="sub-sections-list">
      <!-- generate LIs of each [#main-1 > .sub-section h3 text] -->
    </ul>
    <div class="sub-section" id="m1-s1">
      <h3>Main-1-Sub-1-Headline</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-section" id="m1-s2">
      <h3>Main-1-Sub-2-Headline</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-section" id="main-2">
    <h2>Main-2-Headline</h2>
    <ul class="sub-sections-list">
      <!-- generate LIs of each [#main-2 > .sub-section h3 text] -->
    </ul>
    <div class="sub-section" id="m2-s1">
      <h3>Main-2-Sub-1-Headline</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-section" id="m2-s2">
      <h3>Main-2-Sub-2-Headline</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Old way**

```js
$('.main-section').each(function() {
  var myList = [];
  $(this).find("h3").each(function() {
    myList.push($(this).text());
  });
  $subSectionList = $(this).find('.sub-sections-list');
  $.each(myList, function() {
    var li = $('<li/>').appendTo($subSectionList);
    $('<a/>').attr('href', '#').text(this).appendTo(li);
  });
});
```

Comment: THX to you too NiZa. It was not important for me to accomplish the task by using an array - this was just my helpless idea of how it could be done. Thanks to your answer, i understand now how it could be done, but i prefer the shorter and in my opinion less complicated version of Gene R.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want it even smaller, just with one `each loop`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Wow. Made my Day. One Task, three solutions - a lot to understand for me, thx again.